How do I aggregate this column because I know the right thing is to use group by so what am I doing wrong?
Question:
Portfolio Performance Analysis
Which portfolios have achieved the highest average return rates over the last year?
I have attached how the document looks and this is my locution but I don't know what seems to be the problem.
This what I tried
WITH Latest_Date AS(
SELECT MAX(DATE) AS Latest_Date_Date 
    FROM Performance
),
Previous_Year_Date AS(
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, Latest_Date_Date) AS Previous_Date 
FROM Latest_Date
)
SELECT PortfolioID,  AVG(ReturnRate) AS Avg_Value
    FROM Performance
        WHERE DATE BETWEEN (SELECT Previous_Date FROM Previous_Year_Date) AND  (SELECT Latest_Date_Date FROM  Latest_Date) 
            GROUP BY PortfolioID 
            ORDER BY AVG(ReturnRate) DESC 


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question.
